# Inconsistent initialization

Tags: vim, macvim

MacVim 8.0:

If there is no .vimrc file, `set` shows:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  autoindent          scroll=18           ttymouse=xterm2
  helplang=en         showmatch           wrapmargin=10
  langmenu=none       ttyfast           nowrapscan
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  pythondll=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  pythonhome=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
```

If I create an empty .vimrc file, `set` shows:

```
set
--- Options ---
  helplang=en         scroll=18           ttymouse=xterm2
  langmenu=none       ttyfast
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  pythondll=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  pythonhome=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
```

This differs from the first case in that `autoindent`, `showmatch`, and `wrapscan` are missing.  Why is there a difference?  These options do not seem to be set in /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc.

Starting vim with `-u file` is supposed to use `file` as the startup file.  So if I remove the empty .vimrc--so now I have no .vimrc--and use `-u emptyfile`, where emptyfile is an empty file, I would expect that `set` would show what is listed immediately above.  However, `set` shows something very different:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  helplang=en         scroll=18           ttyfast             ttymouse=xterm
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

Why is this different from the previous case?

(Why do I care?  Because I'm trying to figure out why an initialization file executes properly when it's .vimrc, but not when I run it with `-u`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a `vimrc` at any of the expected locations, Vim sources:

```
$VIM/vimrc
$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
...
```

This is new in Vim 8.0. Before that version, Vim would only source `$VIM/vimrc` in this scenario. The reasoning behind that new feature was allegedly to provide more useful defaults to infrequent users without asking them to write their own `vimrc`.

See `:help defaults.vim`.

---

With a `vimrc` at one of the expected locations (assuming `~/.vimrc` but it can be `~/.vim/vimrc`), Vim sources:

```
$VIM/vimrc
$HOME/.vimrc
...
```

This is the optimal scenario for frequent users, experienced or not: you get the basic behavior plus all your fancy stuff.

---

When pointing Vim to a specific `vimrc` with `-u`, Vim only sources that specific `vimrc`.

This is the absolutist scenario that gives you complete control over Vim's settings. I wouldn't recommend it to inexperienced users.

Comment: Thanks romainl.  My situation is that I have a lot of settings for various purposes in my .vimrc, and I also want a bunch of standard configurations for editing files of a specific type.  Those are provided by someone else.  There are conflicts between the two configurations, though, and I don't want to figure out every one of them, so maintaining two separate vim configurations is easier.  That's why I'm using `-u`, and (now) sourcing the system configuration files in the special `-u` config file.  Actually, I wasn't sourcing default.vim, but night now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found part of the answer.  (I'll post it here for anyone with a similar question, but I don't expect upvotes for either the question or the answer.)

`help initialization` says, among other things:

> If Vim was started with "-u filename", the file "filename" is used.
>       All following initializations until 4. are skipped. $MYVIMRC is not
>       set.

Most of what is between that point and 4. was not relevant to my situation; these are steps that occur only in special circumstances.  However, one item between that point and 4. is:

> b. For Unix, MS-DOS, MS-Windows, OS/2, VMS, Macintosh, RISC-OS and Amiga
>       the system vimrc file is read for initializations.  The path of this
>       file is shown with the ":version" command.

So the system initialization file is not run when `-u` is used.  (This still doesn't fully answer my first question, which mentions the system initialization file on my system.)